# Signtool can't do SHA256 signing on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, digital-signature, code-signing

I have been using SHA1 signing for many years, but from 2016, Windows is forcing developers to use SHA256.

[Windows Enforcement of Authenticode Code Signing and Timestamping](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32288.windows-enforcement-of-authenticode-code-signing-and-timestamping.aspx)

By using Windows 7 SDK signtool the functions to sign SHA-256 is "unknown commands", so this signtool is obsolete as a signtool and shouldn't be used any more.

To sign with SHA256 I downloaded the Windows 8.1 SDK to get signtool.exe which got the new functions(/fd and others). The BAT file and signtool works on Windows 8 and 10, so I know it works, but crashes on Windows 7 when it tries to timestamp the file.

[image: Signing fails]

I use a bat file to sign files, which looks like this(I edited the BAT file so it doesn't show variables, full paths, company name and passwords):

```
Path\signtool.exe sign /f "Path\Certificate.p12" /fd sha256 /p *password* /du "URL" /tr "timestampServer?td=sha256" /td sha256 /d "Product name" "Filename"
```

I guess, I don't have the proper SDK to support some of the functions, but I can't find any info on the internet on how to setup this on Windows 7. I tried to install MS Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64), but still didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a solution for double-signing files in Windows 7.

The trick is to use the **Window 8 SDK** (***not* 8.1 or 10**)! I used this download:
https://developer.microsoft.com/windows/downloads/windows-8-sdk

In Windows 7 x64 make sure to point to the x64 binary (`...\8.0\bin\x64\signtool.exe`)

As a bonus here's a comfortable batch script I made. Simply save it as doublesign.bat and drag a file you want to be signed on that bat-file.

```
@ECHO OFF

set signtool="C:\path to signtool\signtool.exe"
set certfile="C:\path to certificate\cert.p12"
set certpass="Password"
set company="Optional"

echo Signing with SHA-1
%signtool% sign /f %certfile% /p %certpass% /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode %1
timeout /T 3
echo. & echo Signing with SHA-256
%signtool% sign /f %certfile% /p %certpass% /as /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 /td sha256 %1

@PAUSE
```

Comment: I haven't tested this as I moved onto windows 10 not long ago. But your answer is the best at the moment, so I have marked this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is actually way simpler.

The problem is with the time stamp server.

Instead of using **signtool.exe** with this

```
/t http://timestamp.comodoca.com
```

You need to use it like this for SHA1

```
/tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com /td sha1
```

And for SHA256

```
/tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/?td=sha256 /td sha256
```

Comment: Your commands still cause signtool to crash for me; I guess you are using the signtool from the Windows 8 SDK

Answer (score 1):

Seems I'm no good at reading, also I'm answering my own question as others could find it hard to find, just like me.

Windows doesn't support the signtool.exe on Windows 7 any more, so that is why old/obsolete functions like SHA-1 signing is still working, but SHA-256 time stamping is a problem. I found this on MSDN:

> Quote from MSDN: Note  You can only use SignTool to sign your Windows
>   Store app packages on Windows 8 and later or Windows Server 2012 and
>   later. You can't use SignTool to sign app packages on down level
>   operating systems such as Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2.

If you want to read the whole thing then look here:

[How to sign an app package using SignTool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This is only about appx packages, though. It merely states you cannot sign appx packages on Windows versions earlier than 8.

Comment: True, but if you look at how signing works, then signing only adds an overlay to the end of a file. This overlay contains different parameters for the file, so that if the file is changed, the signing is broken and should not be trusted any more. It's like an advanced CRC checksum.

Signing appx packages/files or any other file are technically identical, just like making a CRC checksum of any kind of files. I still believe that my answer is valid till convinced otherwise.

Comment: Different file types are signed differently. But that’s not the point: The article on MSDN is simply not about `.exe` files at all. It applies *only to appx packages.* You tried to use a Windows 8 tool on Windows 7. That didn’t work. It doesn’t mean, however, that you can’t use the Windows 7 SDK version of SignTool to continue signing `.exe` files.

Comment: The windows 7 tool doesn't have the options needed to make SHA-256 signing and timestamping, so it does mean that Windows 7 SDK signtool shouldn't be used(Will add this to the question, good info). I know that MSDN write app packages, but I personally expect that it's all files and they use appx as an example of an file. This assumption is made as I use signtool to sign all kind of files, even file formats I create my self. Feel free to find a better answer, then I will give you the correct answer :)

Comment: @FrankJelstrup `SignTool` can only be used to sign executables [`.exe`], installers, PowerShell scripts [`.ps1`], possibly cabinet files [`.cab`], and a few others - it can't sign `.vbs`, `.cmd`, or `.bat` scripts, Registry files [`.reg`] or hives, among other file types that don't use `#` for a comment. There are other ways to sign code, such as [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.packaging.packagedigitalsignaturemanager.sign?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and `gpg`, with the latter requiring [Gpg4Win](https://www.gpg4win.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Quoting my answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249059/signtool-dual-signing-failure/71632583#71632583
If someone happens to run into the same issue as the solution is really stupid.

> I had the same issue, and that signtool from SDK 8.1 (6.3.9600.17298)
> seems to be VERY particular about the order of command line options !
>
> If I used `signtool sign /v /f my.pfx /p 1234 /fd sha256 /as test.exe`
>
> Dual-signing failed with this error:  `"Multiple signature support is not implemented for this filetype"`   which is actually the same error
> as the one from W10 SDK since `-2147024846/0x80070032` translates to
> (HRESULT)ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED
>
> BUT, if I used `signtool sign /v /f my.pfx /p 1234 /as /fd sha256 test.exe` it worked !
>
> See what I did there? I just swapped the order of /as and /fd sha256 !
>
> I mean this this stuff is just nightmare fuel when you are working on
> something important and then when it's time for production it just
> doesn't work for seemingly no reason. Luckily that was not the case
> this time as I was just testing but I thought I was going mad since I
> first got it to work once, but not again.
>
> To be clear, this is the exact order how I could dual-sign files with
> SHA1 and SHA256, using the signtool.exe from Windows 8.1 SDK,
> available [here](http://cdn1.ksoftware.net/signtool_8.1.zip) (The one
> from W10 SDK still does not work, and the one from V7.1 SDK does not
> support multiple signatures at all)
>
> 1. Sign with SHA1: `signtool sign /v /f my.pfx /p 1234 test.exe`
> 2. Sign with SHA256: `signtool sign /v /f my.pfx /p 1234 /as /fd sha256 test.exe`

Comment: The order of `/fd` shouldn't matter, as I've been using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46713936/6819406) since Windows 8: `SignTool sign /s "MY" /fd "SHA256" /ph /td "SHA256" /tr http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp "Path\to\File"`

Comment: Did you double-sign, with both SHA256 and SHA1 ? That command will only single-sign with SHA256 which does indeed work with no problems in SDK 8 and later. The problem is specific to double-signing which allows for better backwards-compatibility. The bug is probably specific to the 6.3.9600.17298 (8.1 base sdk) version of signtool and might be fixed in later revisions. The problem is that the signtool in W10 SDK (10.0.19041.0) flat out refuses to double-sign. OP did not specifically ask about double-signing though, just SHA256. I'm gonna leave this info up anyway.

Comment: I didn't realize that, thanks =]